# problem with a jQuery function repetition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a form generator but I'm stuck. With this code below I make a form (id=formLabel) visible to type the label of the generated form and submit this formLabel move the label typed in another block where the generated form will be. 
My problem is: the first time I submit the label, one label is created but the second time, the new label typed is created twice, and third the third time...

Thanks for your help !

```js
//Hide the 3 forms
$("#formLabel,#formTxt,#formButton").hide();

//Clic on button label= form visible
$("#label").on("click", function() {
  $("#formLabel").show();
  $("#formTxt,#formButton").hide();

  //submit the form=move the label in a block named left, where the generated form will be.
  $("#formLabel").submit(function(e) {
    var labelEntre = $(".zone").val();
    $("<span style='margin:50px;' id='span' style='float:left;'>" + labelEntre + "</span>").appendTo($("#left"));
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: please create a working example of your problem so that we can check and understand your problem

Comment: It's because every time `#label` is clicked you're creating a new `submit` event handler. Separate those event handlers.

Comment: and avoid to use `id`